# why STUN doesn't work with symmetric NAT?

Tags: nat, asymmetric-routing

I read this line from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN#Limitations).

> "***STUN does work with three types of NAT: full cone NAT, restricted
>   cone NAT, and port restricted cone NAT***. In the cases of restricted
>   cone or port restricted cone NATs, the client must send out a packet
>   to the endpoint before the NAT will allow packets from the endpoint
>   through to the client. **STUN does not work with symmetric NAT**"

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because STUN(external server), cant know which port will be given to the client by NAT-device. In symmetric NAT, client gets unique port(ip:port in pool situation) on each connection

Answer (score 21):

Let's say we have a STUN server at address `stun_addr` and a server at address `srv_addr`. Using STUN typically goes something like this:

1. Client connects to the STUN server at `stun_addr` through NAT device. The NAT device translates the source address to `natted_addr_1`
2. STUN server tells client the address from which it received the connection, which is `natted_addr_1`
3. Client contacts the server at `srv_addr` through the NAT device, and tells the external system to use `natted_addr_1` if it wants to reach the client
4. External system sends something to the client using `natted_addr_1`

This will only work if the NAT device uses `natted_addr_1` for both the communication to the STUN server and the other external system. More specifically, it only works if the NAT device will deliver the packets which arrive in step 4 to the client.

A symmetrical NAT device will use a different translation in steps 1 and 3 because the destination address of the traffic is different. In step 3, the source address in the packets to the server is translated to some other address `natted_addr_2`.

The NAT device only knows about these combinations of source and destination addresses and will only allow these back in:

- From `stun_addr` to `natted_addr_1`
- From `srv_addr` to `natted_addr_2`

Unfortunately, the server has been told to use `natted_addr_1` but packets from `srv_addr` destined to `natted_addr_1` will be rejected by the NAT device because of the NAT Address:Port restriction in-place.

To be more correct, 'address' should be replaced by 'address/port' in this answer, because NAT devices will work with the combination of IP address and port numbers.

Comment: Great explanation. This has helped me understand why STUN doesn't work for symmetric NATs. What I'm still struggling with is, in the world of WebRTC, will candidates generated via STUN on a address or port restrict cone NAT succeed? It seems to be in all of these cases, UDP hole punching is going to fail. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This sounds like a new question to me. Since terminology on different NAT-types can be confusing, ou could ask a new question on the site with some more context, if you like.

Comment: Sure, here you go http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/nat-types-effect-on-webrtc-communication